# Dealing with Definitions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the expected value, but I seem to be having trouble. I turned the input values to integers and I think that is where the error is coming from. I know the int cannot convert an empty string to the integer, but when testing this I had a value.

Error:

```
 TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

```
def print_menu():
print('1. Add a Stock')
print('2. Recommend Sale')
print('3. Quit')
print()

expected_value = {}

menu_choice = 0
print_menu()
while menu_choice != 3:
    menu_choice = int(input("Type in a number (1-3): "))
    if menu_choice == 1:
        print("Add Name, Prices, Risk, Shares")
        name = input("Name: ")
        price = input("Buyers Price: ")
        Cprice = input("Current Price: ")
        srisk = input("Risk: ")
        sshares = input("Shares: ")
       Expected_Sale_value = ((int(Cprice) - int(price)) - int(srisk) * int(Cprice)) *    int(sshares)
        expected_value[name] = Expected_Sale_value
    elif menu_choice == 2:
        print("Expected Sale values")
        for x in expected_value.keys():
            print("Stock: ", x, "\tExpected value:", Expected_Sale_value[x])
        print()
    elif menu_choice != 3:
        print_menu()
```

I am new to python, and I know python has its tricks! Saying that I ask if there are any tips or you see something I can improve on please give me insight.

EXAMPLE(IDLE):

1. Add a Stock
2. Recommend Sale
3. Quit

Type in a number (1-3): 1
Add Name, Prices, Risk, Shares
Name: Google
Buyers Price: 21
Current Price: 20
Risk: 1
Shares: 2
Type in a number (1-3): 2
Expected Sale values
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 25, in 
    print("Stock: ", x, "\tExpected value:", Expected_Sale_value[x])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What did you actually type into the prompts? Also, please provide the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: I will edit my question in just one minute sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error where you're using the wrong variable name. Here are the relevant lines:

```
for x in expected_value.keys():
    print("Stock: ", x, "\tExpected value:", Expected_Sale_value[x])
```

In the `print` statement you are indexing into the variable `Expected_Sale_value` rather than `expected_value`. `Expected_Sale_value` is an integer, rather than a dictionary, so you get an exception.

A slightly more "Pythonic" way of doing the loop would be:

```
for key, value in expected_value.items():
    print("Stock: ", key, "\tExpected value:", value)
```

Comment: That corrects all errors, but it still leaves me with the question: When using integers can I use decimals in the input?

Comment: @Kelsey: If you want to handle non-integer values, you'll just need to change the calculation of `Expected_Sale_value` in the other part of the code. Replace some or all of the `int` calls with calls to `float` (or maybe `Decimal` from the `decimal` module, if you need exactly precise computation at the cost of some speed).

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in expected_value.key():
```

should be

```
for x in expected_value.keys():
```

also use `raw_input`

Comment: raw_input() was renamed to input()

From http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html